# top, bottom, left and right properties can't be changed by keyframe if it used calc() in IE nor Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

This code runs perfectly in chrome, but it doesn't in IE11 nor Edge, top and left animations are not being affected.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .foo {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 9px);
        left: calc(50% - 42px);
        font-size: 10px;
        animation: enter 1s 1s infinite alternate;
      }

      @keyframes enter {
        to {
          font-size: 40px;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo">I hope to be moving</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, if the initial state of top and left is just a measure (without calc) it works perfectly. Why is happening that?

Note: I can't use transform here, because I need the object to be aligned in the middle of the screen and then go to the top, left corner.

Comment: I don't know why it goes wrong the way it does, but as a workaround, you can use the margin trick for a start position: `top: 50%; margin-top:-9px;
        left: 50%; margin-left:-42px;` in the default style; and set the margins to 0 in the keyframe.

Comment: Yep, finally I just did that. Thank you so much :)